Getting the last value from an ElasticSearch index
I'm trying to get the latest value from my Elasticsearch index but when I execute this, it prints everything in the index on the console.
I have also tried doing it using the "DateTime" field but every time I get all the documents from the index printed.
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "earthquake-v2"
    query => '{
     "size": 1,
     "sort": [
       {
         "DateTime": {
           "order": "asc"
         }
       }
     ],
     "query": {
       "match_all": {}
     }
   }'
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

This is the output that I am getting. It's printing everything in my index, all the documents:
> {
> "Gap" => "59",
> "parsedDateTime" => "2015-12-31T22:26:08.000Z",
> "Magnitude" => "4.30",
> "Distance" => "2",
> "Longitude" => "72.6379",
> "MagType" => "Mb",
> "@version" => "1",
> "Latitude" => "40.8745",
> "Depth" => "40.30",
> "DateTime" => "2016-01-01 03:26:08",
> "Source" => "us",
> "RMS" => "1.21",
> "@timestamp" => 2024-05-20T07:40:44.169218400Z
> }
> {
> "Gap" => "219",
> "parsedDateTime" => "2015-12-31T22:15:43.000Z",
> "Magnitude" => "1.09",
> "Distance" => "17",
> "Longitude" => "-119.6086",
> "MagType" => "ML",
> "NbStations" => "9",
> "@version" => "1",
> "Latitude" => "41.8857",
> "Depth" => "4.99",
> "DateTime" => "2016-01-01 03:15:43",
> "Source" => "NN",
> "RMS" => "0.10",
> "@timestamp" => 2024-05-20T07:40:44.169218400Z
> }
> {
> "Gap" => "115",
> "parsedDateTime" => "2015-12-31T21:06:45.000Z",
> "Magnitude" => "2.60",
> "Distance" => "0",
> "Longitude" => "-155.0622",
> "MagType" => "ML",
> "@version" => "1",
> "Latitude" => "19.5748",
> "Depth" => "14.40",
> "DateTime" => "2016-01-01 02:06:45",
> "Source" => "hv",
> "RMS" => "0.44",
> "@timestamp" => 2024-05-20T07:40:44.166006100Z
> }

What I'm hoping for is to just get the last or most recent value from the respective field in my Elasticsearch index which I can then use to further check in my local data file and if more records are there then make a new index. TIA!

The size parameter in logstash.conf allows you to set the maximum number of hits returned per scroll.
I recommend to use curl command and run it with DateTime sorting and size:1 instead of Logstash.

The following command should return only the latest data according to
DateTime field.

curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/earthquake-v2/_search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "DateTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}'

or compressed one:
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/earthquake-v2/_search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{"size":1,"sort":[{"DateTime":{"order":"desc"}}]}'


Note: In curl command, check http/https and add -u elastic:password flag if you need authentication.


Thank you for your response. So, doing this in logstash isn't possible for now? My intention was to do this.
"What I'm hoping for is to just get the last or most recent value from the respective field in my Elasticsearch index which I can then use to further check in my local data file and if more records are there then make a new index."
Please note that my query works as it should in the DevTools and getting me the desired result.

You're welcome @DanyalDanish. It looks like it's not possible to do that with logstash-input-elasticsearch. If you want to stick with Logstash maybe logstash-http-input can help.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html
